# Coldfusion debugger for Intellij?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am looking for the configuration debugger for the `Coldfusion 11` for the `IDE IntelliJ`. I have found debugger integration for `Eclipse`, however, I prefer Intellij over Eclipse, I am trying to figure out the debugger configuration for IntelliJ.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-coldfusion.html. Note that it's Ultimate only feature.

Comment: I went through this configuration but it's basically for run configuration. It does not provide detail configuration of intellij. I was wondering if anyone knows about it. Ya, it's for IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: You are right, debugger is missing: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83102
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95071.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install CFBuilder within IntelliJ as a plugin? Try that and see if you like the debugging capabilities within CFBuilder.
http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-builder.html

One other option is to try FusionDebug which is product from Intergral folks who are an amazing group.
http://www.fusion-debug.com/